# consequences of having several IOS distribution provisioning profiles linked to one appId

Tags: ios, expo, apple-developer-account

We have an app that is already in the App Store. Currently I (very junior dev not really supervised on this specific subject :-) ) have passed it from bare to managed using expo go. To finalize the IOS settings, I have to upload the distribution certificate as well as the distribution provisioning profile. Problem : the provisioning profile linked to this appId has expired a while ago and it can't be downloaded any longer nor uploaded to expo dashboard.
I've thought of creating a new one, which will be identical (except for the name). Is there any counter-indications to having two provisioning profiles linked to the same appId and with the same distribution type (appStore) ? If I create a new provisioning profile, will the app in store still be linked to the former (the expired one) ? Thanks a lot for any clarifications, I am a bit lost as to what should not be tampered with once the app is already in store.

Steps. App passed from managed to bare with expo and eas.
Current stage - trying to upload the relevant IOS credentials to expo dashboard.

Comment: Yes, you can use the new provisioning profile. The expired one is no longer valid and it will not throw errors.